# C++: Template Specialization causes different result in Debug / Release

Tags: c++, templates

In the following code, I create a `Builder` template, and provide a default implementation to return nothing. I then specialize the template with int, to return a value 37.

When I compile with `-O0`, the code prints 37, which is the expected result. But when I compile using `-O3`, the code prints 0.

The platform is Ubuntu 20.04, with GCC 9.3.0

Can anyone helps me understand the behavior?

builder.h

```
class Builder {
        public:
                template<typename C>
                static C build() {
                        return 0;
                }
};
```

builder.cc

```
#include "builder.h"

template<>
int Builder::build<int>() {
        return 37;
}
```

main.cc

```
#include "builder.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        std::cout << Builder::build<int>() << '\n';
}
```

makefile

```
CXX_FLAG = -O0 -g
all:
        g++ $(CXX_FLAG) builder.cc -c -o builder.o
        g++ $(CXX_FLAG) main.cc builder.o -o main
clean:
        rm *.o
        rm main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a forward declaration for `build<int>()` to `builder.h`, like so:

```
template<>
int Builder::build<int>();
```

Otherwise, while compiling `main.cc`, the compiler sees only the generic template, and is allowed to inline an instance of the generic `build()` function. If you add the forward declaration, the compiler knows you provided a specialization elsewhere, and will not inline it.

With `-O3`, the compiler tries to inline, with `-O0` it will not inline anything, hence the difference.

Your code actually violates the ["One Definition Rule"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition): it will create two definitions for `Builder::build<int>()`, but they are not the same. The standard says the result is undefined, but no diagnostics are required. That is a bit unfortunate in this case, as it would have been helpful if a warning or error message was produced.

Comment: Make sense! Thank you.

Comment: The relevant part of the standard is http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.expl.spec-7.